# Are ['null','','undefined'].indexOf(str) < 0 and (str !== null || str !== '' || str !== undefined) equivalent?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, indexof

Would you know whether the following two functions are equivalent?

```
function validate(str)
{
  return ( ['null','','undefined'].indexOf(str) < 0 );
}
```

and

```
function validate(str)
{
  return (str !== null || str !== '' || str !== undefined);
}
```

The question primarily arises because of the apostrophes of null and undefined in the indexOf array.

Comment: no, because the first code searches for the actual strings `'null'` and `'undefined'` .. the second code checks if str is `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

As you see, they are not returning the same result.

The main problem is, you convert a value to a string for comparing in `validate1`. If you have a string with this value, then you get a wrong result.

```js
function validate1(str) {
    return ['null', '', 'undefined'].indexOf(str) < 0;
}

function validate2(str) {
    return str !== null || str !== '' || str !== undefined;
}

console.log([null, undefined, 0, '', false, 'null', 'undefined'].map(v => [v, validate1(v), validate2(v)]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course is not. For example, to check value to 'undefined' you need check data type (!) a not compare to an undefined value. Use typeof operator to get type.